# Are asio socket thread-safe for read / write?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using asio::ip::tcp::socket class in synchronous mode.
I have an instance of a socket that is a connection between at server and a client.
I have one thread that is writing in the socket, and one thread reading from the socket.
Do I need a mutex to lock the calls to the socket ?
I know that socket class is not thread-safe, but I'm assuming that it mostly can create problems when 2 threads are trying to both read from a socket or write to a socket.
Is it still unsafe if each thread does a different operation on the socket ?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. Because you want to use another thread while working in "synchronous mode" I think you want to add another thread because of communication and not for performance. If you do it for communication you should take a step back and try to use "asynchronous mode". Asio (asynchronous input/output) allows you to write a single threaded non blocking server which can serve a lot of clients and the code looks like its synchronous.

Comment: `Synchronous send, receive, and connect operations are thread safe with respect to each other, if the underlying operating system calls are also thread safe. This means that it is permitted to perform concurrent calls to these synchronous operations on a single socket object. Other synchronous operations, such as open or close, are not thread safe.` https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/doc/asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html